# Change ASP.Net Session ID - Call from Desktop App via AJAX

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, vb6, session-cookies

I have an old VB6 application - I need to shell out to a ASP.net site via a web browser. I have the browser opening and calling the ASP site successfully. I need the VB6 app to know when the Web Browser session is closed. The VB app form (or save button) needs to be disabled when the web browser session is open. (I don't want to use the process Id of the windows process to check this.)

My thought are:

- Cross domain cookies perhaps? (security?)
- I have my VB6 app able to call server WebMethods
- Saving a session ID in the database which is usedbut both apps?

Some advice would be excellent. Many thanks.

Comment: Might be best to simply have a call to a server function (Web Service) which lets you know the session is live or not (directly), (Function SessionsExist() As Boolean or whatever you wish to call it)  and use that information in your VB app,  (Link to web services: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh128052.aspx)

Comment: Yes, sounds good - but how do I know the ASP.NET_SessionId in the VB 6 app when I call SessionsExist() in the Web Service?

Comment: Use the SessionIDManager object (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sessionstate.sessionidmanager?view=netframework-4.7.2)  Read the second paragraph under the heading of REMARKS in documentation... (paragraph starts with...'By default, the SessionID value is sent in a cookie')

Answer (score 0):

Internal Company Applications.

**Desktop App (VB6)**

- Code to allow VB6 apps to contact Asp service. On any Asp.Net page create an extra [WebMethod] in this case a ‘IsWindowOpen’ method has been added to the test.aspx page (see red text beow)
- Send a JSON message to the ASP.Net service to query if a WINDOWS_STATUS Session variable is set (this tells us if a browser window is open\closed).
- When shelling out to the Asp.Net site with parameters (plan Id etc.) we’ll send in an extra param for ‘Session Id’.
- Randomly generate a Session Id in VB6 app [random: 24 char long, lower case, and digits between 0-5], this is replicating how the Asp.Net framework is going to generate its own Session Id for communication between the HTML and C#. We will then override the Asp.Net Session Id given to us by Asp.Net with our own random generated Session ID.

Check if ASP.Net session variable is set in VB6:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim objHTTP As Object
    Dim Json As String
    Dim result As String

    ' === Check if Browser Session is open ===
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    url = "http://dub-iisdev/SessionTest/test.aspx/IsWindowOpen"

    objHTTP.open "POST", url, False

    objHTTP.setRequestHeader("cookie") = "ASP.NET_SessionId=" + txtCookie.Text ' Required twice
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader("cookie") = "ASP.NET_SessionId=" + txtCookie.Text ' Required twice

   objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"

   objHTTP.send (Json)

   result = objHTTP.responseText

   txtOutput.Text = result

   Set objHTTP = Nothing
End Sub
```

**ASP.Net**

We’ll need a few pieces of plumbing here :
A small method for setting ASP.Net session IDs
A small closing aspx page which will run some code when we leave the browser, and
Some extra C# methods and JavaScript in our existing pages.

**1. Setting Session ID:**

Copy variable from old session to new location

```
protected void ReGenerateSessionId(string newsessionID)
{
    SessionIDManager manager = new SessionIDManager();
    string oldId = manager.GetSessionID(Context);
    string newId = manager.CreateSessionID(Context);
    bool isAdd = false, isRedir = false;
    manager.RemoveSessionID(Context);
    manager.SaveSessionID(Context, newsessionID, out isRedir, out isAdd);

    HttpApplication ctx = (HttpApplication)HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance;
    HttpModuleCollection mods = ctx.Modules;
    System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule ssm = (SessionStateModule)mods.Get("Session");
    System.Reflection.FieldInfo[] fields = ssm.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    SessionStateStoreProviderBase store = null;
    System.Reflection.FieldInfo rqIdField = null, rqLockIdField = null, rqStateNotFoundField = null;

    SessionStateStoreData rqItem = null;
    foreach (System.Reflection.FieldInfo field in fields)
    {
        if (field.Name.Equals("_store")) store = (SessionStateStoreProviderBase)field.GetValue(ssm);
        if (field.Name.Equals("_rqId")) rqIdField = field;
        if (field.Name.Equals("_rqLockId")) rqLockIdField = field;
        if (field.Name.Equals("_rqSessionStateNotFound")) rqStateNotFoundField = field;

        if ((field.Name.Equals("_rqItem")))
        {
            rqItem = (SessionStateStoreData)field.GetValue(ssm);
        }
    }
    object lockId = rqLockIdField.GetValue(ssm);

    if ((lockId != null) && (oldId != null))
    {
        store.RemoveItem(Context, oldId, lockId, rqItem);
    }

    rqStateNotFoundField.SetValue(ssm, true);
    rqIdField.SetValue(ssm, newsessionID);
}
```

Your first landing page will set the new Session ID (from VB6) param sent into the server– using out ReGenerateSessionId class above.

After this code executes out instance to Asp.Net and our instance of VB6 will have the same Session Id for HTTP communication

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Simulate Session ID coming in from VB6...
    string sessionId;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    sessionId = "asdfghjklqwertyuiop12345" [24 char - a to z (small) & 0-5]
    // Set new session variable and copy variable from old session to new location
    ReGenerateSessionId(sessionId);

    // Put something into the session
    HttpContext.Current.Session["SOME_SESSION_VARIABLE_NAME"] = "Consider it done!";
}
```

**2. Open\Closing Browser**

One of the ASP.Net pages needs to have three new WebMethods: SetOpenWindow, SetClosingWindow and IsWindowOpen

**Opening the Browser:**

C#. SetOpenWindow:
This will be called from your first (or any required) HTML pages via the .ready JavaScript. When the page has loaded the JavaScript will simply fire an Ajax call to the SetOpwnWindow web method. The method will set a Session variable WINDOW_STATUS to OPEN.

```
[WebMethod()]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false)]
public static string SetOpenWindow()
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session["WINDOW_STATUS"] = "OPEN";
    return "Status:" + HttpContext.Current.Session["WINDOW_STATUS"];
}
```

ASPX. Call SetOpenWindow from Ajax once the page has loaded. This sets the WINDOW_STATUS to OPEN

```
<script src=”Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'test.aspx/SetOpenWindow',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {}//alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        });

        $("#form1").submit(function () {
            submitted = true;
        });    
    });
</script>
```

**Closing the Browser:**

On pages where the browser window can be closed call JavaScript to catch when the browser window is closing (handy to add this to your master page instead of to each page!). This calls the ClosingSessionPage aspx page to run the SetClosingWndow webmethod:

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
    var submitted = false;

    function wireUpWindowUnloadEvents() {
        $(document).on('keypress', function (e) { if (e.keyCode == 116) { callServerForBrowserCloseEvent(); } }); // Attach the event keypress to exclude the F5 refresh
        $(document).on("click", "a", function () { callServerForBrowserCloseEvent(); }); // Attach the event click for all links in the page
    }

    $(window).bind("onunload", function () { if (!submitted) { callServerForBrowserCloseEvent(); event.preventDefault(); } });
    $(window).bind("beforeunload", function () { if (!submitted) { callServerForBrowserCloseEvent(); event.preventDefault(); } });
    window.onbeforeunload = function () { if (!submitted) { callServerForBrowserCloseEvent(); } };
    window.onunload = function () { if (!submitted) { callServerForBrowserCloseEvent(); } };
    $(window).bind("onunload", function () { if (!submitted) { callServerForBrowserCloseEvent();event.preventDefault();} });

    function callServerForBrowserCloseEvent() {
        window.open("ClosingSessionPage.aspx", "Closing Page", "location=0,menubar=0,statusbar=1,width=1,height=1"); }

    function btn_onclick() { open(location, '_self').close(); }

</script>
```

The close JavaScript method above redirects to a closing aspx page to run some ajax and then close itself – The Ajax calls SetClosingWindow the session WINDOW_STATUS variable to CLOSED.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server" title="Closing Session">

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: 'test.aspx/SetClosingWndow',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: "",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    window.close();
                } });  });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <p>Closing browser session, please wait.</p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**C# SetClosingWindow**
Called from Ajax JavaScript when the Browser window is closing and sets WINDOW_STATUS to CLOSED:

```
[WebMethod()]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false)]
public static string SetClosingWndow()
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session["WINDOW_STATUS"] = "CLOSED";
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock((Page)(HttpContext.Current.Handler), typeof(Page), "closePage", "window.close();", true);
    return "Status:" + HttpContext.Current.Session["WINDOW_STATUS"];
}
```

**3. Is Browser Open?**

ASP.Net WebMethod called by VB6 whenever it needs to know if the Browser window is Open or Closed.

```
[WebMethod()]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false)]
public static string IsWindowOpen()
{
    string isWindowOpen = HttpContext.Current.Session["WINDOW_STATUS"] != null ? HttpContext.Current.Session["WINDOW_STATUS"].ToString() : "CLOSED";

    return "IsWindowOpen:" + isWindowOpen;
}
```